# Requesting Android run-time permissions using try and catch

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am wondering would it make sense to use Java's **try** and **catch** statements to request user app permissions, if we get SecurityException?

Rough example would be:

```
int hasReadExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (hasReadExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // inform user
            }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_CODE_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_OPEN_PROJECT);
    return;
}
myFunction();
```

versus

```
try {
    myFunction();
} catch (SecurityException) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                 MainActivity.this,
                 new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                 REQUEST_CODE);
       return;
}
```

Pros and cons for both approaches?

Comment: did you try this ?

Comment: the problem with using try/catch statement is you should catch all possible exceptions that can happen inside try{} block. There are other exceptions that could happen and if not handled crash ur app. Performance difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts on unchecked exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Recalling that `SecurityException` is a runtime exception, I emphasize this part:

> Runtime exceptions represent problems that are the result of a programming problem, (...)

So I understand that requesting permission after a thrown `SecurityException` means that the program has a problem of not checking whether the app has some specific permission before calling an operation. I particularly avoid developing problematic programs.

Nonetheless, both codes will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering about a *tiny* window of opportunity for the permission to be removed between the calls to `checkSelfPermission` and `myFunction`.  This would be an argument in favour of the `try ... catch` option.  However, some experiments I've done suggest that, while permissions can be added to a running app, if permissions are removed, then the app is killed.

All the small examples I see show calling `checkSelfPermission` just before the permission is needed, but in some cases it may be better to ensure that you have permissions early, and you can simplify subsequent code by assuming that you continue to have permission.

Comment: `if permissions are removed, then the app is killed.` this is untrue.